# How to check if a two data frame have the same column names?

Tags: r

I have two data frames like this:

```
quest1 <- c(5,5,5)
quest2 <- c(5,5,5)
quest3<- c("a","b","c")
quest4 <- c(7,7,7)
quest5 <- c(8,8,8)


myquest1 <- data.frame(quest1,quest2,quest3)

myquest2 <- data.frame(quest4,quest5)
```

How can I check if they have the same column names with an ifelse or if loop statement **with a warning or stop function**?
Or is there an other..? I would prefer the the former.

Comment: I think you want `names(myquest1) %in% names(myquest2)`, and it turns out that your example show none being the same

Comment: @RichardScriven

See my edit. I forgor a part.

Comment: @Trik23 Do you want to check if all the columns are the same in both datasets ? Suppose `names(myquest2) <- c("quest1", "quest2");  names(myquest2) %in% names(myquest1)#[1] TRUE TRUE`

Comment: @akrun

Yes, all of them. Like a comparision. If they are not, give stop/warning.

Comment: @Trik23 Why not try `identical(sort(names(myquest1)), sort(names(myquest2)))`

Comment: Or even `stopifnot(all(names(myquest1) %in% names(myquest2)))`

Comment: @akrun

Thank you to for the solution!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821533/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tell-if-many-data-frames-stored-in-one-list-contain-the/56821789#56821789

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you need is something like the following using a function.

Using your example:

```
quest1 <- c(5,5,5)
quest2 <- c(5,5,5)
quest3<- c("a","b","c")
quest4 <- c(7,7,7)
quest5 <- c(8,8,8)

myquest1 <- data.frame(quest1,quest2,quest3)
myquest2 <- data.frame(quest4,quest5)
myquest3 <- data.frame(quest1,quest2,quest3)


my_func <- function(x,y) {
    for (i in names(x)) {
      if (!(i %in% names(y))) {
          print('Warning: Names are not the same')
          break
      }  
      else if(i==tail(names(y),n=1)) {
          print('Names are identical')
      }
    }
}


> my_func(myquest1,myquest2)
[1] "Warning: Names are not the same"
> my_func(myquest1,myquest3)
[1] "Names are identical"
```

Comment: The users in the comments helped me out. But Ill accept your anwser because they have not yet gave one here. You give an intersting approach to a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: And if you program my_func to also keep a counter, print each failed col name and break after it is complete if the not same counter is greater than one, then you get a nice list of names to chase down and fix! Great function!