# Is there an easy way to tell if many data frames stored in one list contain the same columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

I have a list containing many data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6, C = LETTERS[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6, C = LETTERS[1:5])
df3 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, C = LETTERS[1:5])
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want to know if every data frame in this list contains the same columns (i.e., the same number of columns, all having the same names and in the same order).

I know that you can easily find column names of data frames in a list using `lapply`:

```
lapply(my_list, colnames)
```

Is there a way to determine if any differences in column names occur? I realize this is a complicated question involving pairwise comparisons.

Comment: `all(sapply(my_list[-1], function(x) identical(names(x), names(my_list[[1]]))))` maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another `base` solution with `Reduce`:

```
!is.logical(
  Reduce(function(x,y) if(identical(x,y)) x else FALSE
         , lapply(my_list, names)
         )
)
```

You could also account for same columns in a different order with

```
!is.logical(
  Reduce(function(x,y) if(identical(x,y)) x else FALSE
         , lapply(my_list, function(z) sort(names(z)))
         )
)
```

As for what's going on, `Reduce()` accumulates as it goes through the list. At first, `identical(names_df1, names_df2)` are evaluated. If it's true, we want to have it return the same vector evaluated! Then we can keep using it to compare to other members of the list.

Finally, if everything evaluates as true, we get a character vector returned. Since you probably want a logical output, `!is.logical(...)` is used to turn that character vector into a boolean.

See also here as I was very inspired by another post:

[check whether all elements of a list are in equal in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813526/check-whether-all-elements-of-a-list-are-in-equal-in-r)

And a similar one that I saw after my edit:

[Test for equality between all members of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313463/test-for-equality-between-all-members-of-list)

Comment: This does not return `TRUE` if all dataframe columns match. Try -`df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6, C = LETTERS[1:5]);
df2 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6, C = LETTERS[1:5]);
df3 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 2:6, C = LETTERS[1:5]);
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3);Reduce(identical, lapply(my_list, names))` That's because after the first pair `identical` will try to compare a logical (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) with character vector (names) which will always return `FALSE`.

Comment: I tested it with two identical DFs and it worked (i.e., ```list(df1, df2)```) - should've tested a third. The problem was that ```Reduce()``` evaluated ```identical(names(df1),names(df2))``` to ```TRUE```. Obviously, ```TRUE != names(df3)```. I've modified the answer after finding another question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813526/check-whether-all-elements-of-a-list-are-in-equal-in-r

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid pairwise comparison by simply checking if the count of each column name is `== length(my_list)`. This will simultaneously check for `dim` and `names` of you dataframe -

```
lapply(my_list, names) %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  table() %>% 
  all(. == length(my_list))

[1] FALSE
```

In base R i.e. without `%>%` -

```
all(table(unlist(lapply(my_list, names))) == length(my_list))

[1] FALSE
```

or sightly more optimized -

```
!any(table(unlist(lapply(my_list, names))) != length(my_list))
```

Comment: Cool! Is there a base R solution?

Comment: This is base R. You only need `magrittr` for `%>%`. You can separate out the steps if you want to use only base R.

Comment: ```all(table(Reduce(c, lapply(my_list, names)))==length(my_list))``` Do we really need `magrittr`?

Comment: @Shree makes sense. piping does make the solution cleaner. Cheers. +1

Comment: `unlist` is simpler than `Reduce(c, ...)`

Comment: @alistaire No idea how I missed `unlist`. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```r
!any(is.na(dplyr::bind_rows(my_list)))

 # [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Nice. Although binding all the rows itself has no value. I'd suggest `!any(is.na(dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(my_list, head))))` for better speed with large dataframes. Not totally sure though.

Comment: @Shree depending on the size of the dataframes (maybe thousands of rows or even more) your suggestion could be an improvement.

Comment: This assumes there weren't any `NA`s beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
k <- 1
output <- NULL
for(i in 1:(length(my_list) - 1)) {
 for(j in (i + 1):length(my_list)) {
  output[k] <- identical(colnames(my_list[[i]]), colnames(my_list[[j]]))
  k <- k + 1
 }
}
all(output)
```